# Antenna Performance with plastic fasten

Tags: rf, antenna

I need to put dipoles antennas in a restricted area with lot of movement. I'm wondering if I fasten the end of the antenna will affect performance, because the fasten needs to be grounded.

Is like when human touch TV antennas can improve signal reception because body acts as an extension of antenna. Or in a oppositive way when touching Iphone 4 can degrade signal quality because your fingers are in contact with antennas (http://ipod.about.com/od/iphonetroubleshooting/qt/Iphone-4-Antenna-Problems.htm).

The difference is that no human is touching the antenna but a plastic fasten.

Hope that the following diagram could help.
[image: End of the antenna fastened with plastic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your picture is not the way to use a quarter wave monopole. A monopole needs to be vertical to the ground plane. If you want a "flat" antenna then use a patch antenna: -

[image]

[image]

Calculator [**here**](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CAUQjhxqFQoTCNqC49aNmskCFYFeDwodlrAJmw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dxzone.com%2Fdx31174%2Fmicrostrip-patch-antenna-calculator.html&psig=AFQjCNHwx0GBGR1ObwoSrLxkM1bxpyYMug&ust=1447940576805742)

Comment: Thanks Andy, but this picture is referential is supposed to be a dipole antenna. I have omitted that info sorry. I'll update the topic.

Comment: @progloverfan It makes no difference, a dipole shouldn't be used this way either.

Comment: Ok Andy, in terms of performance it shouldn't but actually it could be used in this way (thanks for clarification).  In any way what you think about the fasten ?

Comment: @progloverfan You're missing the point. It's the wrong tool for the job, so your fastener should be the least of your worries.

Comment: Matt is quite correct - I'm not going to stick my neck out to agree to any of this madness - if you believe the dipole works ok flat then it's because you've tested it and it works to your satisfaction (you believe). If you have tested it then test it with a plastic disc. If you haven't tested it to prove it works against a ground plane then listen to what I'm saying.